# Max(datetime) ignore seconds

Tags: sql-server, datetime, group-by, max

I got my sql query working but when I find a date with the same hour and minutes, I am not able to make the query works. For example: 
[image]

On the column "trans_date" I can't use my query because with max(trans_date) I am getting no results, somehow the sql is ignoring the seconds.

This is my complete sql sentence:

```
SELECT till.code,art.description
FROM [TCPOS4].[dbo].[transactions] as tra,
TCPOS4.dbo.articles as art,[TCPOS4].[dbo].[trans_articles] as tro,
[TCPOS4].[dbo].[tills] as till,[TCPOS4].[dbo].[shops] as shop 
where tra.till_id=till.id and shop.id=till.shop_id and tro.transaction_id=tra.id and  
art.id=tro.article_id  and tra.trans_date =(select max(trans_date) 
from tcpos4.dbo.transactions as t2 where t2.till_id=tra.till_id  and  trans_date  > '2016-10-26 00:00:0.000' and trans_date< '2016-10-27 00:00:00.000' )
group by till.code,art.description
```

With this query I am getting for each "code" from the 2016-10-26 to 2016-10-27 the max transaction_date, but I am not getting any information from the code "5446". I should get "TABLE CHOCOLECHE-CONGUITOS" because it's the max trans_date in the range.

Comment: is the trans_date within the range '2016-10-26 00:00:0.000' to '2016-10-27 00:00:00.000' exclusive?  what date does the row you don't get have?

Comment: I guess the problem is somewhere around `INNER JOIN`s. Tend to use explicit join syntax instead of oldschool joins "by comma and predicate in where".

Comment: The date of the row is the first one of the picture, which has almost the same date than the other one. I think that the problem is there because I have been experimenting and the error appears I have the same hour and minute. Well, I don't have an error, the query just ignore the code '5446'

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with a different approach like the following?

```
SELECT code, description
 FROM
 (
  SELECT till.code, art.description,
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY till.code ORDER BY trans_date DESC) RowNum
   FROM [TCPOS4].[dbo].[transactions] AS tra
   LEFT JOIN [TCPOS4].[dbo].[tills] AS till
    ON tra.till_id=till.id
   LEFT JOIN [TCPOS4].[dbo].[shops] AS shop
    ON shop.id=till.shop_id
   LEFT JOIN [TCPOS4].[dbo].[trans_articles] AS tro
    ON tro.transaction_id=tra.id
   LEFT JOIN TCPOS4.dbo.articles AS art
    ON art.id=tro.article_id
 ) sbt
 WHERE RowNum=1
```

In this way you will get one result for each  till.code  even if you have the same exact date.

You can add more fields in the ORDER BY if needed.

EDIT: removed art.description in PARTITION BY.

EDIT 2: converted with LEFT JOIN

Comment: Can you try removing art.description in PARTITION BY ?

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: I have to say that I am not getting two rows like the picture, I get nothing. Well, I get the other codes that are grouped but nothing of the code '5446'

Comment: Your approach was like using inner joins.
I edited it with LEFT JOIN in my answer.
Can you test it and see if it shows any row with NULLS?
If it is the case, replace LEFT and put INNER one by one and try to see if results changes.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
...CAST(tra.trans_date AS DATE) = (select CAST(max(trans_date) AS DATE)...
```

Comment: you need to experiment, remove some of the conditions and find out which condition is stopping it from appearing - we have little info to go on - is it one of the other conditions causing it to not appear - what if you remove the date condition completely, or make it always true - does the row appear in the list then?

Comment: I have been experimenting with the query and I realized that the problem is because of the date. This query is working me for everything, I only have problems when the hour and minute from a row is the same. The max(date) ignore the seconds from my datetype, don't know why.

Comment: > '2016-10-26 00:00:0.000' that has to be actually greater than the exact day.  What time values are actually present when it goes wrong?

Comment: I see, so some sort of rounding is causing tra.trans_date =(select max(trans_date) .. to find new record, even though the record has to exist - could you use one of the format commands to change to a text format?  It sounds like worrying behaviour though

Comment: you haven't used any alias on select max(trans_date) - I'd check that that is ok